# Storing comma separated lists in a SQL database - Is it right?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, normalization, database-normalization

I have a MySQL database which contains 2 tables. The first table simply consists of **products**. The second consists of **users**. I am using PHP to handle the info.

*In the users table I want to define what products that user is allowed to view.*

I originally thought that I could achieve this by creating a column in the **users** tables containing a list of comma separated values which would correspond to the products that user is allow to see (*basically a list of product_id's that are available to that user.*)

Since I decided on this method I have done a little research and I've seen people suggesting that it doesn't follow the rules of database normalization and can quickly create redundancies.

If there is a better way to do it, I would sure appreciate some insight from anybody who can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

Create another table, that links users to products, such as `users_to_products` and have fields `user_id` and `product_id`

This will allow you to query the database to find which products a user can see:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, p.id, p.name FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN users_to_products AS up ON u.id = up.user_id
LEFT JOIN products AS p ON p.id = up.product_id
WHERE u.id = ?
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not the best way. You should create one more table with products that user is allowed to view with structure:

`user_id` and `product_id`

both referencing to ids in tables where you store your users and your products.

If you store comma separated list in MySQL you can sooner or later get problems with searching in such tables. For example if you would like to find user who are allowed to view product 2 and 5, it could be impossible just in MySQL

Comment: thank you for the quick response! Am I still allowed to store the comma separated values in the product_id field? or is that not best practice?

Comment: No, for each product user is allowed you should create new record. So if user 1 is allowed to view product 2 and 7, you should have 2 records in your table 1 2 and 1 7

Comment: Wow that seems like a lot of data! - but if that's the correct way, i'll do it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Unless you fail to index your tables sensibly, "a lot of data" shouldn't ever be a problem in a database - the only issues are likely to be ISPs that imposes restrictions on volumes of data, not the database technologies.... it's what databases are designed to do

Answer (score 3):

**NO!!! DO NOT DO IT WITH A COMMA SEPARATED LIST**

You will hate yourself in years to come if you do. The proper way to handle relationships like this is with a [Junction Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

You would have something like:

```
CREATE TABLE UserProducts
(
        UserID INT NOT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users (UserID),
        ProductID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Products (ProductID),
    PRIMARY KEY (UserID, ProductID)
);
```

This allows proper referential integrity management as a conmma separated list would allow any `ProductID` to be entered, whereas the foreign key ensures a valid productID is entered. It is much easier to search for users with a specific product:

```
SELECT  u.UserID
FROM    Users AS u
        INNER JOIN UserProducts AS up
            ON up.UserID = u.UserID
WHERE   p.ProdcutID = 3;
```

As opposed to:

```
SELECT  UserID
FROM    Users
WHERE   CONCAT(',', ProductList, ',') LIKE '%,3,%';
```

It also allows you to get the product name and query using indicies, i.e. if you wanted a list of products a specific user is allowed to use you'd need to join to the product table using a very inefficient predicate:

```
SELECT  p.Name AS Product
FROM    Users AS u
        INNER JOIN Products AS p
            ON CONCAT(',', u.ProductList, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', p.ProductID, ',%')
WHERE   u.UserID = 1
```

With a junction table you can simply use:

```
SELECT  p.Name AS Product
FROM    UserProducts AS up
        INNER JOIN Products AS p
            ON p.ProductID = up.ProductID
WHERE   u.UserID = 1;
```

If you ever needed the Product IDs in a comma separated list you can easily accomplish this using GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT  up.UserID, GROUP_CONCAT(up.ProductID) AS ProductList
FROM    UserProducts AS up
GROUP BY up.UserID;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are good points raised in the answers, but just to demonstrate why the comma separated list can be a problem. Any check for an item in the comma separated list can't use an index which means any general check will be slow.

Not a problem if you are just checking a single row. For example you have narrowed the search down to a particular user and want to check if that user has access to a single product, but if you want to find all the users who have access to a single product you are forcing a non indexed table scan (ie, mysql will have to read every single row and process the field).

MySQL does support the FIND_IN_SET() function which does make searching a comma separated field easy, if not fast. But it only works to find a single value in a set. You cannot easily take one set and compare it to another set.

Comment: +1 for explanation of ___why___ a comma-separated list is a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Mainly 3 tables like `user, product and user_products`.

```
TABLE : user_products
Fields : id, user_id, product_id
```

Where user_id refer to ID of User Table and product_id refer to ID of Product table.

Answer (score 0):

You should make 3 tables:

Users
Products
User_Products

Then you take the UserID from Users and the ProductId from Products and insert them into the User_Products table, matching the user id to the allowed product id's